# Why is Alternative energy most commonly stored in metal acid batteries?

Tags: batteries, renewable-energy, solar-cells

Why is alternative energy most commonly stored in relatively expensive metal acid batteries, which have a short life, rather than hydrogen gas accumulated through electrolysis?

Hydrogen is a versatile energy source itself and with low cost technology is a cheap, clean and reliable fuel.

Comment: If it was reliable, in terms of we can reply on it not to ignite, that would be great, it would be in every car in a few years, but we can't. That's one reason.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are generating electricity (say from wind or PV) and you want electricity, then there are two obvious cycles:

- for lead-acid you charge and discharge the battery;
- for hydrogen you crack water, store the hydrogen, and then run a fuel cell.

Lead-acid batteries can have charge-cycle efficiencies of around 80%, perhaps more.  (Lithium-ion I think is even better.)

Electrolysis has an efficiency in the range of 50-70%, and fuel cells are in the range 40-60%.  So the overall efficiency of the cycle is in the range 20-40%.  This is not even slightly competitive.

On a large scale you can perhaps either burn the hydrogen to make steam for a steam turbine generator, or may be run a gas turbine directly.  These systems have efficiencies that might touch 50%:  [this page and its links](http://www.eia.gov/tools/faqs/faq.cfm?id=107&t=3) says that natural gas power generation can be about 43% efficient, in 2015.  This is no better than fuel cells, but the plant might be cheaper.

You can also run an internal combustion engine with hydrogen: that's not a good way of generating electricity, but it might be reasonable if you want to run a car.  I haven't looked up figures but I suspect that hydrogen to fuel cell to electric drive is better.

I have not touched on the energy density question: to get anything competitive you need to compress the hydrogen which requires yet more energy, some of which you may hope to recover.  Even then I am not sure how competitive it is.

This is why lead-acid batteries are used.